# Create user in sitecore using powershell

Tags: sitecore

**Problem:** I want to create user in sitecore using Microsoft powershell script. I do not want to use powershell provided by sitecore.

I am able to create user using powershell script within the sitecore. But the requirement is to create new user in each environment using powershell scripts while doing setup.

Answer (score 0):

A Sitecore user is a normal ASP.NET Membership user in the Sitecore core SQL database. (default but depend on your config). And in Microsoft PowerShell you can do a SQL query.

First create the user by using stored procedure aspnet_Membership_CreateUser and use as ApplicationName 'sitecore' and use the sitecore domain.

This SQL creates an valid Sitecore user:

```sql
declare @salt nvarchar(128)
declare @password varbinary(256)
declare @input varbinary(512)
declare @hash varchar(64)

-- Change these values (@salt should be Base64 encoded)
set @salt = N'eyhKDP858wdrYHbBmFoQ6DXzFE1FB+RDP4ULrpoZXt6f'
set @password = convert(varbinary(256),N'mypassword')

set @input = hashbytes('sha1',cast('' as  xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable(''@salt''))','varbinary(256)') + @password)
set @hash = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:variable(''@input'')))','varchar(64)')

-- @hash now contains a suitable password hash
-- Now create the user using the value of @salt as the salt, and the value of @hash as the password (with the @PasswordFormat set to 1)

DECLARE @return_value int, 
  @UserId uniqueidentifier 

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_CreateUser] 
  @ApplicationName = N'sitecore', 
  @UserName = N'sitecore\startup', 
  @Password = @hash, 
  @PasswordSalt = @salt, 
  @Email = N'jan@test.com', 
  @PasswordQuestion = N'nope', 
  @PasswordAnswer = N'nope', 
  @IsApproved = 1, 
  @CurrentTimeUtc = '2017-03-03', 
  @CreateDate = '2017-03-03', 
  @UniqueEmail = 1, 
  @PasswordFormat = 1, 
  @UserId = @UserId OUTPUT 

SELECT @UserId as N'@UserId' 

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

And add the rols you need. 'sitecore\Sitecore Client Users' is the rol you need to login into the CMS.

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles_AddUsersToRoles] 
   @ApplicationName  = N'sitecore'
  ,@UserNames =  N'sitecore\startup'
  ,@RoleNames =  N'sitecore\Sitecore Client Users'
  ,@CurrentTimeUtc =  N'2017-03-03'
GO
```

This example create a user 'startup' with password 'mypassword' with minimal rights.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
Actually we are looking for loading sitecore context in windows powershell.
 
Also, we are not allowed to directly interact with the sitecore database

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [Sitecore Powershell extensions to create users in Sitecore](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/security/new-user):

example

```
PS master:\> New-User -Identity michael -Enabled -Password b -Email batman@gmail.com -FullName "Bruce Wayne"
```